# Effecient way to get read mappedmemoryfile as new data arrived using MemoryMappedViewAccessor

Tags: c#-4.0, memory-mapped-files, mapped-memory

I am looking for an efficient way to read mappedmemoryfile using the MemoryMappedViewAccessor create from the CreateViewAccssor method. I really do not want to just use a while(true) loop and exit the loop when needed.
I did not see any Read method that could be used in the while statement that just sits there until it receives a mapped memory, and then executes the code in the while loop.
What I really need is maybe a read method where several various event could make the method execute the code in the while loop such as, CanellationToken, defined event, or new mapped memory to be read. But I doubt any such method exist.
So if anyone has some code or link to code examples on an efficient way to read mappedmemory file using  MemoryMappedViewAccessor as new data arrives please let me know. The reading of the mappedmemoryfile data shall be read in a task thread which is supplied a cancellation token.

Comment: Right now, it appears the auto reset event or manual reset event is the way to go.